# What is the best practice of connecting(?) sql values?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, maui

i am writing a app in maui and im using sqlite, but have a problem with connecting a values.
I have three plans of create a table/tables but idk what is the best option and what practice i should use in next projects.

So, i wanna create a drag and drop page to manage workers shifts, like you can drop a 1h block and can resize to more to create a full filled work plan on day.
In next step i wanna add option to get a month summorise of this days and view like a report and print option.

First i made at the beginning, but it was projected to something like one page to display and one to add this, and i don;t know how to implement it to drag and drop.
[image]

Second is have date and second value is serialized json of all shiftdatas.

[image]

Third is like second, but have every value in ShiftData and connecting it with ShiftChain.
[image]

I'm try to search what is useully used.

Try search how others use serialized in databases.

Comment: is there a point to second and third, you don't add any new information to the database with the new tables, so they are superfluous, only when you want to normalize your structure for example you would add more table, but i n your case there is no need, for the third, a bridge table is necessary to represent a m:n relationship(in normalized way), which you also don't have

Comment: Okey so my first project of database is the best of this three, but is also good in overview?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "best practice" questions are off-purpose for StackOverflow. If you have encountered a **specific problem** in your code, then re-word the question to ask for a solution to that actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your first database design there is no real shift. Every person works independantly from another. This means you can have worker A working on a particular date from 6:00 to 14:00 and worker B working from 6:30 to 13:45.

In your second database design nothing is gained, because you want an 1:1 relation.

Your third database design is flawed. You have a table called Shifts, but it contains dates, so this is rather a date table. Then there is a table you call ShiftChain, but you give it a Shift ID, so this seems to be the real shift table.

If you want to have real shifts, where, say, a particular day has a shift from 6:00 to 14:00 and another from 14:00 to 22:00 (or even with day overlaps like one shift from 10:00 to 18:00 and another from 19:00 to 3:00 the next day), you could have these tables:

- worker (**worker_id**, name, ...)
- shift (**shift_id**, from_datetime, to_datetime)
- shift_work (**worker_id, shift_id**)

Comment: I understand, but it possible to have 2 workers in store at the same time, it not common but possible and time to time i wanna it can be used.
In second i gain only one row per date, but can be difficult to use this data.
I have table with workers and store, but not include there because my problem is only with that table.
At the moment my database looks like https://imgur.com/a/uvikiuQ but imo it can by difficult to implement.

Comment: So there are stores. And one worker always works in one store only? And a shift refers to working hours in a store, too? And are there real shifts, i.e. fixed working hours like in a factory where all workers either work in shift 1 from 6:00 to 12:00 or shift 2 from 12:00 to 18:00 or shift 3 from 18:00 to 24:00? Or do you mean by "shift" merely the hours an employee worked in the shop?

Comment: Sure i use bad word to describe i have in mind only hours an employee worked in the shop and can be different every month.

Comment: For this your ERM looks fine to me.

Comment: Okay, so i only need add bridge like @nbk showed to me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, you don't, because there are no shifts. nbk told you the same as I did in my answer, that in order to assign shifts to workers, which would be an n:m relation (m workers per shift, n shifts per worker) there must be a table to represent this association. But there are no shifts; there are just hours an employee worked, and for this your design with the worker ID in the shift table (1:n relation = a shift refers to one worker only) is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As described in my commant for multiple worker that work in mutiple shifts, (Relationn n:m) you need a bridge table)

```
Shiftdata                    Shift_Worker           Worker               Store
Shift_ID                     ShiftID                Worker_ID            Store_ID
Starttime(with date)         WorkerID               PersonalNumber       Store_Name
Endtime( With Date)                                 Name                 Store_Address    
StoreID                                             Surname              Store_City
                                                    Sex
                                                    Birthdate
```

Sorting and filtering of times without date is somewhat complicated and should be avoided when possible